# Lebesgue measure and Left and right inverse distribution functions

Tags: continuity, lebesgue-measure, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure and $F(x)$ be a distribution function (i.e. right continuous and non decreasing with range [0,1]. Show that
$$
\lambda\big\{u\in (0,1]: F_l^{\leftarrow}(u) \neq F_r^{\leftarrow}(u)\big\} = 0,
$$
where

- $F_l^{\leftarrow}(u) = \inf\{t: F(t) \geq u\}$
- $F_r^{\leftarrow}(u) = \inf\{t: F(t) > u\}$

I think the proof would be about showing that $F_l^{\leftarrow}(u) = F_r^{\leftarrow}(u)$ for every $u \in (0,1]$,  (since $\lambda${$\emptyset$} = $0$), but I do not have any idea about how to proceed. I also tried to draw the function and see the behaviour in case of jump but nothing, this kind of funcion really confuse me.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be mistake in the definitions. If $F$ never takes the value $u$ then the second infimum is $\infty$.

Comment: If $F(t)=0$ for $t <0$ and $1$ for $t \geq 0$ then the conclusion fails.

Comment: You are right, it is F(t)>u, thanks

Comment: The property that you need here is that $F$ is monotone, so the set of points of discontinuity is countable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Froda%27s_theorem

Comment: Do you mean so that all discontinuity points are singleton? But what next?

Comment: This shows that the set of discontinuity points of a monotone function is countable and hence of measure zero. The function that you are interested in is basically the inverse of $F$ (which is also monotone).